# Showing only one sub-site in navigation?

Tags: navigation

I'm just creating the sub/side navigation (or 'Current Navigation' as sharepoint calls it) and have set it to show subsites, however, it drills down to two levels when we'd only like it to drill down to one...

To give a really terrible example, with all of the following as sub-sites:

```
Colours
- Blue
- Red
- Green
Numbers 
- One
- Two
- Three
```

I only want it to display 'Colours' and 'Numbers' and then the rest of the options when the user clicks into them, otherwise the Current Navigation list is around 4x as long as the actual content area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to uncheck `Show subsites` on your 1st level subsites ('Colours' and 'Numbers').

**Edited**

If your 1st level subsites are more or less static you can mimic list of subsites with custom links (on top site) and have `Show subsites` on 1st level subsites (to show 2nd level ones when you navigate to 1st level). IMHO there is no way you can have dynamic navigation as you required by using OOTB `Show/Hide subsites`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately if I uncheck Show subsites it hides all of them, including the 1st level sites

Comment: @Nick: Sry, I have missed that you want to preserve subsites on 2nd level. I have updated my answer.